# firebase EmailAuthProvider token

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I created a user using email and password and now I want to store the token for that user so he doesn't need to sign in everytime. I managed to get the token after the first sign in using

```
firebase.auth()
  .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.loginEmail, this.loginPassword)
  .then(res => {
    res.getToken().then(token => {
      firebase_token = token
    })
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error.toString())
  })
```

But now I can't use the token to sign in either using credential.

```
var cred = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, firebase_token)
firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(cred).then(function (user) {
  console.log('using google auth provider')
  console.log(user)
})
```

or custom token

```
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(firebase_token).then(function (user) {
  console.log(user)
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error(error)
})
```

So what is the point of the token? It would work for other Auth like Google and Facebook but I just wanted a simple email and password...

Do I have to resort to store the email and password on the device in order to sign them in automatically?

Comment: Firebase sessions are indefinite. Once the user signs in, that same user should remain signed in. Firebase ID tokens (obtained via getToken) will be refreshed whenever they expire and an Auth operation is run.

Comment: Sounds like an answer @bojeil! :-)